# How to iterate in a directory and stop at a particular level using C?

Tags: c, process, directory

I am trying to print the names of all the processes currently in the system, in the terminal. For that I have to get into all the directories named after the process ID in the "proc" directory. So I am looping till before the "acpi" directory and trying to read the status file in each process directory. But I don't exactly understand how to read a file in a directory which is inside a directory. On running my code below :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <dirent.h>

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{

DIR* FD;
struct dirent* in_file;
FILE  *process_file;
char ch, pname[1024];
int i=0;

FD = opendir ("/proc");

while ((in_file = readdir(FD))) 
{
    if (strcmp (in_file->d_name, "acpi") == 0)
        break;

    else 
    {
        opendir(in_file->d_name);

        process_file = fopen("status", "r");

        while( ( ch = fgetc(process_file) ) != '\n' )
        {
            pname[i] = ch;
            i++;
        } 
        printf(" %s \n",pname);
        fclose(process_file);


        closedir(in_file->d_name);
    }

}

closedir(FD);
return 0;

}
```

I get the error :

```
myps.c: In function ‘main’:
myps.c:38:13: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘closedir’ from incompatible pointer type
    closedir(in_file->d_name);
             ^
In file included from myps.c:5:0:
/usr/include/dirent.h:149:12: note: expected ‘struct DIR *’ but argument is of type ‘char *’
 extern int closedir (DIR *__dirp) __nonnull ((1));
            ^
```

Comment: `closedir` takes a `DIR *` not a `const char *`

Comment: Please clarify your question, is the issue what you mention in the title or the error you get?

Comment: FD is my DIR *.   I am not sure the approach I am following to open a directory inside a directory is correct. My issue is the one mentioned in the title.

Comment: @dothermitian - You should probably consult the man pages, Its very clearly stated there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a good example of when to use a recursive function.

The function would take a directory name, open that directory, and loop through the results.  For each result that is not `.` or `..`, call the `stat` function to get status on each entry.  Then use the `S_ISREG` and `S_ISDIR` macros against the file mode to see if it's a regular file or a directory.  If it's a directory, build a new string from the parent directory and the one you just found and pass that to the recursive function call.

So the function would look something like this:

```
void processDirectory(char dirname[])
{
    struct stat statbuf;
    DIR *dir;
    struct dirent *de;
    char *subdirname;
    int rval, ;

    if ((dir = opendir(dirname)) == NULL) {
        perror("Failed to open directory %s", dirname);
        exit(1);
    }
    while ((errno = 0, de = readdir(dir)) != NULL) {
        rval = stat(de->d_name, &statbuf);
        if (rval == -1) {
            perror("stat failed"); 
            exit(1);
        }

        if (S_ISREG(statbuf.st_mode)) {
            // process as a regular file
        } else if (S_ISDIR(statbuf.st_mode)) {
            if (strcmp(de->d_name, ".") && strcmp(de->d_name, "..")) {
                subdirname = malloc(strlen(dirname) + strlen(de->d_name) + 2);
                if (subdirname == NULL) {
                    perror("malloc failed");
                    exit(1);
                }
                strcpy(subdirname, dirname);
                strcat(subdirname, "/");
                strcat(subdirname, de->d_name);
                processDirectory(subdirname);
                free(subdirname);
            }
        }
    }
    if (errno && (errno != ENOENT)) {
        perror("Failed to read directory %s", dirname);
        exit(1);
    }
    closedir(dir);

}
```

Comment: That was helpful. Thanks

Comment: No problem.  Fee free to [accept this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if you found it useful.

Answer (score 0):

To solve the error, save the directory pointer you open. Then use that to close the directory.

`DIR *process_dir =  opendir(in_file->d_name);`

`closedir(process_dir);`